# Help solving equation $x^{ax}=(1-a+x)^{1-a+x}$

Tags: numerical-methods, problem-solving

I would to solve the following equation either symbolically or numerically, but I am unsure how:

$$x^{ax} = (1-a+x)^{1-a+x} \quad\text{ where }a,x\in (0,1)$$

I have fixed various values for a and plotted this equation. I believe that each a is mapped to a unique x and that x is increasing in a. However, I am unsure how to show any properties about this solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It appears that one requirement is $a\gt x$.  That's the first obvious thing I can see...

Comment: Using Desmos (or your favorite implicit graphing application) you can plot the solution set and it appears to be continuous, just use $y=a$.  Probably the simplest approaches would include taking limits at the endpoints of the interval; if $a\to 0$ then $x$ is forced to do the same, as $a\to 1$, we have $x$ increasing a bit more slowly, just slightly larger than $\frac 12$ in the limit.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot expect a closed form solution for the zero of function
$$f(x,a)=(1-a+x)^{1-a+x}-x^{a x}$$ even using special functions.

If you draw the zero level of the contour plot of the function (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B%281+-+a+%2B+x%29%5E%281+-+a+%2B+x%29+-+x%5E%28a+x%29%3D%3D+0%2C+%7Ba%2C+0%2C+1%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+1%7D%5D)), you notice a nice smooth function.

Solving for a few values of $a$, you can generate the following table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & x(a) \\
 0.0 & 0.000000 \\
 0.1 & 0.079640 \\
 0.2 & 0.142752 \\
 0.3 & 0.198384 \\
 0.4 & 0.249508 \\
 0.5 & 0.297633 \\
 0.6 & 0.343677 \\
 0.7 & 0.388258 \\
 0.8 & 0.431833 \\
 0.9 & 0.474761 \\
 1.0 & 0.500000
\end{array}
\right)$$

which is "almost"
$$x(a)=\frac 12 a^{\frac 34}$$
obtained using a quick and dirty nonlinear regression $(R^2=0.9996)$.

Using this result as a starting point, Newton method should converge quite fast. Let us try for $a=0.345$; the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.225079 \\
 1 & 0.221839 \\
 2 & 0.221838 
\end{array}
\right)$$

As @abiessu commented, we could also start with $x(a)=\frac a2$ which for the working case would lead to the same number of iterations.

**Edit**

Since the proposed estimate $x_0=\frac 12 a^{\frac 34}$ looks to be quite good, we could afford one iteration of Newton method and obtain
$$x_1=x_0+\frac{(1-a+x_0) \log (1-a+x_0)-a x_0 \log (x_0)}{a \log (x_0)-\log (1-a+x_0)+a-1}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & x_0=\frac 12 a^{\frac 34} & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 0.00 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 &  0.000000 \\
 0.05 & 0.052869 & 0.043191 &  0.043191 \\
 0.10 & 0.088914 & 0.079635 &  0.079640 \\
 0.15 & 0.120514 & 0.112422 &  0.112429 \\
 0.20 & 0.149535 & 0.142745 &  0.142752 \\
 0.25 & 0.176777 & 0.171260 &  0.171265 \\
 0.30 & 0.202680 & 0.198381 &  0.198384 \\
 0.35 & 0.227521 & 0.224394 &  0.224396 \\
 0.40 & 0.251487 & 0.249507 &  0.249508 \\
 0.45 & 0.274713 & 0.273879 &  0.273879 \\
 0.50 & 0.297302 & 0.297633 &  0.297633 \\
 0.55 & 0.319332 & 0.320871 &  0.320872 \\
 0.60 & 0.340866 & 0.343674 &  0.343677 \\
 0.65 & 0.361955 & 0.366113 &  0.366118 \\
 0.70 & 0.382643 & 0.388248 &  0.388258 \\
 0.75 & 0.402964 & 0.410130 &  0.410147 \\
 0.80 & 0.422949 & 0.431806 &  0.431833 \\
 0.85 & 0.442623 & 0.453317 &  0.453358 \\
 0.90 & 0.462011 & 0.474700 &  0.474761 \\
 0.95 & 0.481130 & 0.495990 &  0.496078 \\
 1.00 & 0.500000 & 0.500000 &  0.500000 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I am surprised by how close $\frac{1}{2}a^{\frac{3}{4}}$ is to the real function ... I wonder if there is anything more to that, or whether it is just a coincidence. In any case, this is a very nice solution! +1

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee. Thanks. The factor $\frac 12$ is obvious and looking at the plof gives the idea of a power smaller that $1$. But is it a pure coincidence. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking for a command like the contour plot one you used - I appreciate it. Can you explain what you did for the nonlinear regression?

Comment: @N.C. I just looked at the numbers. There are two points which are obvious and it is clear that the deviation from linearity implies a power a bit smaller than $1$. May be, you could accept the answer clicking the green arrow. Cheers :-)